# Save function changes bool type in python

Tags: python

When i try to load the save i made this `testbool = bool(loaded_list[0])` turns testbool to true, please help me out here, thank you very much.

This is the entire code,

```
menu = True

testbool = False

def save():
    f = open("testsave.txt", "w")
    list = [
        str(testbool)
    ]
    for item in list:
        f.write(item)
    f.close()
    print(testbool)
while menu:
    ans = input("Hello 1 or 2?\n")
    if str(ans) == "1":
        print("Hello World!!")
        save()
        menu = False
        run = True
    if str(ans) == "2":
        print(testbool)
        f = open("testsave.txt", "r")
        print(testbool)
        loaded_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
        print(testbool)
        testbool = bool(loaded_list[0])
        print(testbool)
        if ans == "4":
            quit()
        menu = False
        run = True

while run:
    print("Hello World")
    save()
    ans = input("4?")
    if ans == "4":
        quit()
```

so the `if str(ans) == "1":` block works perfectly fine but its the second one that i have an issue with.

Comment: if you are using python3 then `str(ans)` isn't doing anything

Comment: `bool()` of *any* non-empty string is True.  Try `testbool = loaded_list[0] == "True"`.